# Opera extension manifest file

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, opera, browser-addons

I have created an Opera extension, but have a question about the "manifest.json" file.

Specifically, I'm not sure what version I should put in "minimum_opera_version".

According to the documentation (which all points to the chrome developer API), based on the API calls I make the minimum version is Chrome 26.

However what version of Opera is that? How can I figure out what minimum version of Opera the extension requires?

Answer (score 0):

Opera stable is now at version 49. First ChrOpera was ver 15. It's mainly those on XP that might need to resort to a much older build than current. You don't need to state minimum_version at all in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The `minimum_opera_version` usually depends on the APIs you use in your addon. For example if you use `Alarm` API in your add-on then check from which version of Opera does the support for `Alarms` API exists and configure accordingly.
-> https://dev.opera.com/extensions/apis/